# Why is my led(stm32f3-discovery board) is not glowing after applying delay?

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32f3

Is there any mistake I am making in applying delay the delay?

This is the code I am working with to blink led 3 and 4 after with a delay.

```
use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use stm32f30x_hal as hal;
use hal::delay::Delay;
use hal::prelude::*;
use hal::stm32f30x;
use panic_halt;

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let device_p = stm32f30x::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let core_periphs=cortex_m::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut reset_clock_control = device_p.RCC.constrain();
    let mut gpioe = device_p.GPIOE.split(&mut reset_clock_control.ahb);
    **let mut flash = device_p.FLASH.constrain();
    let clocks = reset_clock_control.cfgr.freeze(&mut flash.acr);
    let mut delay = Delay::new(core_periphs.SYST,clocks);**
    let mut led_3 = gpioe
        .pe9
        .into_push_pull_output(&mut (gpioe.moder), &mut (gpioe.otyper));
    let mut led_4=gpioe.pe8.into_push_pull_output(&mut gpioe.moder,&mut gpioe.otyper);


    loop {
        led_3.set_high();
        **delay.delay_ms(2_000_u16);**
        led_4.set_high();

    }
}
```

If I am not using delay part it is working fine

Comment: What exactly do you see without the delay?

Comment: okay, so if i remove the delay part from my code that is flash, clocks & delay and simply provide the  'led_3.set_high();'  inside loop with then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you set up your `clocks` wrong. For the delay to work correctly you should use the system clock.

This is how to create the `Delay` for STM32 based on this [sample](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f4xx-hal/blob/v0.8.3/examples/delay-blinky.rs) (stm32f4xx, but should work for you, too):

```rust
// Set up the system clock. We want to run at 48MHz for this one.
let rcc = dp.RCC.constrain();
let clocks = rcc.cfgr.sysclk(48.mhz()).freeze();

// Create a delay abstraction based on SysTick
let mut delay = hal::delay::Delay::new(cp.SYST, clocks);
```

where `dp` are my device peripherals (e.g. `let dp = stm32::Peripherals::take().unwrap()`) and `cp` are the core peripherals.

So this uses the [`sysclk`](https://docs.rs/stm32f3xx-hal/0.6.1/stm32f3xx_hal/rcc/struct.CFGR.html#method.sysclk).

Alternatively you could also try to replace your delay with `cortex_m::delay(8_000_000);`, where the delay is given using the number of clock cycles.

Comment: Hi frankenapps, thanks for the answer but i think my device peripheral is not supporting this command line "let clocks = rcc.cfgr.sysclk(48.mhz()).freeze();"  **it is asking for missing arguments inside freeze()**

Comment: Ah, I see. You have to add the `ACR`, too: [`freeze`](https://docs.rs/stm32f3xx-hal/0.6.1/stm32f3xx_hal/rcc/struct.CFGR.html#method.freeze)

Comment: Did you try my second suggestion? It should be simpler...

Comment: i provide the flash.acr inside freeze but nothing happen.

Comment: I tried the second suggestion **cortex::delay** and it worked. Thanks for the help @frankenapps

Answer (score 0):

In the loop  you set the LED high `led_3.set_high();`. However never set `led_3` low again so it would never blink. So change your loop to:

```rust
led_3.set_high();
led_4.set_low();
delay.delay_ms(2_000_u16);
led_4.set_high();
led_3.set_low();
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @Gerhard. I was trying to glow led 3 then led 4 with some time gap by providing delay. Although I tried your suggestion also but no result.

Comment: @Samar: What does no result mean? The software enters an infinite loop.

Comment: Led didn't glow.

Comment: This sounds like your program panics when executing the delay statement. Maybe try running it using semihosting or use OpenOCD to get a trace: https://docs.rust-embedded.org/debugonomicon/